# automatically detect iframe blocking

Tags: php, iframe

I use iframes in my news aggregation web app. While I am careful to always credit and link publishers, I also respect those who chose to block iframes (by not implementing sneaky workarounds). My question is how I can automatically detect whether iframes will be blocked, given the URL of the external page in question. So far i am using this code:

```
        //get external html
        $p = file_get_contents($this->scrape_ready_url);
        //check for blocker
        $pattern1 = "/window\.self.{1,10}window\.top/";
        $s1 = preg_match($pattern1, $p);
        //check for blocker2
        $pattern2 = "/window\.top.{1,10}window\.self/";
        $s2 = preg_match($pattern2, $p);
        //condition response
        if ($s1 === 1 || $s2 === 1) {
            $this->frame = "blocked";
        } else {
            $this->frame = "not_blocked";
        }
```

This works most of the time (so far), but many publishers such as [yahoo](http://celebrity.yahoo.com/news/why-anna-kendrick-done-musicals-singing-f-cking-214852836.html) use slight variations of the "self !== top" code which makes preg_match not work. I am wondering if there is any universal/general test that I can implement to know whether or not a given URL will block an iframe or not.

thanks

Comment: Is it an option to do the detection clientside, in javascript?

Comment: From my research it seems that clientside dom parsing of an external file is not possible. That said, I could potentially load the html using PHP, (or an iframe) and then parse with JS. If you have a client-side solution, I would like to know it.

Comment: I did some tests on clientside detection. I hoped i'd be able to analyze the iframe content, or at least its length to see if something valid was loaded, but i quickly ran into cross-domain issues. You can however improve your server-side detection by using an additional check on the header. Check if there is a header `X-Frame-Options` and if its value is `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`

Comment: good call, forgot about that. implementing now.

Comment: Sometimes the iframe gets blocked [by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336591/) even if the 3rd party URL allows being embedded in iframes. You'd think it would be possible to detect that client-side.